# How can I display an image in a ms access 2013 report using relative paths stored in a field of a database

Tags: image, ms-access, report

I have a simple database with table tblUsers containing the following fields:

id-number
name-short text
surname-short text
picture-short text

In the picture field I store the relative path to the linked image file for every record (using a form and a file dialog box for selecting picture).
I'm currently trying to make a report with 9 id cards on a page layout in which for every record, using an image control, to show the picture for the record by recreating the full path to the file and assingning it to the control's Picture property.

So, as an example:

I have 9 records with the values of the field Picture equal to: john_doe1.jpeg to john_doe9, stored as text.
When I load the report, I want to be able to see the 9 id cards with their respective photo atached.
I tried using the on current event for the report with this code

```
Private Sub Report_current()
    Me.txtPathImg = Me.GetDBPath & [tblUsers.picture]
    Me.imgControl.Picture = Me.txtPathImg
End Sub
```

but all I got is one picture for all the records in the report.

How can I display the correct picture for every record in report view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bound image control, i.e. set it's control source, e.g.

```
=GetDBPath() & "\" & [picture]
```

Then you don't need any code.

`GetDBPath()` must be a public function for this.

Or build the full path in a query, use that query as recordsource, then you can directly bind the image control to the full path.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried with control source like you said, but I don't know why it didn't work even if I made the GetDBPath() public function in the Report_Open event. Then I constructed the path to the photo in the control source using CurrentProject.Path and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

hellow S.Overflow
tbl1students:

ID_FullName - dataType : text

Image_Path - dataType : text  such as (D:\Imagefolder\FullName.jpg) you know that? ok

............

now create report wizard from tlblstudents table and then open report ac design

ok :

Add Imageframe from toolsbox

then make  controlsource :Image_path

..............

you don't need to VBA cods to do that

Comment: Please make an attempt to format your code when posting answers, and explain how your answer helps solve OP's problem.