# displaying linked image in Access report

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an MS-Access table that has a field containing a path to a .jpg file. I am trying to create a report that displays several fields from the table, and displays the actual graphic (photo of an inventory item), rather than the path to the graphic.

Yes, those worked fine for a form. I am able to take a value from a field in the record, and set "picture" property in the image control on a form. But I need to be able to get this to work on a report. I have tried the following:

```
Private sub Detail_Paint()
    Me.Controls.Item("_Image").Picture = Me.Controls!main_photo.Value
End Sub
```

This code sets the photo source. Unfortunately, it sets the same photo for all records in the report. Help me Obi-wan Knobi. Your my only hope.

Comment: See if this helps... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285820/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-in-a-form-a-report-or-a-data-acces

Comment: Bind Image control to field with file path. No VBA needed. Review https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=73766 - especially post #17.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display an image in a ms access 2013 report using relative paths stored in a field of a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265600/how-can-i-display-an-image-in-a-ms-access-2013-report-using-relative-paths-store)

Comment: if you want to get rid of the linked concept and work on a purely dynamic way with efficient Image storing/retrieving you can take a look to my article : https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33716/Defeating-the-device-independent-bitmap-dib-format.html